# Find files containing pattern1, where the next line does not contain pattern2

Tags: regex, shell, sed, private-key

I'm trying to search for plaintext private keys. A simple search for "BEGIN.*PRIVATE" returns many false positives, as many are stored encrypted in the following format:

```
-----BEGIN ... PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
```

The desired output is a list of all filenames containing plaintext private key(s). How many are in a file, or how often each occurs, are problems I would deal with afterwards.

I have a very ugly, annoyingly fragile solution:

```bash
for i in $(find temp_git/ -type f) ; do sed -n '/BEGIN.*PRIVATE/ {N ; /ENCRYPTED/!p}' "${i}" | sed -E "s#.*#${i} : Plaintext PK#" | sort -u 2>/dev/null ; done
```

Due to the insufficiently quoted path in the last sed statement, this fails on various filenames, and I'm loathe to invest more time in a clearly suboptimal solution. It is surely possible to do this succinctly with sed, but having failed to hack anything useful together with awk, I'd be very interested in an *awk solution (with awk, I imagine I could also drop the 'for i in subshell...').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
find temp_git -exec perl -lne '
    print $ARGV if /BEGIN.*PRIVATE/ and readline !~ /ENCRYPTED/
' {} +
```

- `-l` removes newlines from Perl's input and adds them to `print`;
- `-n` processes the input line by line, running the code for each line;
- `$ARGV` contains the name of the currently opened file;
- [readline](http://p3rl.org/readline) reads the next line from the file, `!~` negates matching against `/ENCRYPTED/`.

Comment: Your knocking this out in a few seconds or minutes is... embarassing. Perl hadn't even occurred to me.

Comment: It should be pointed out that a rare edge case may occur where a line is matched and so is the following line and is discarded; this precludes the discarded line from being matched with the first match.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/BEGIN.*PRIVATE/{N;/\n.*ENCRYPTED/!F;D}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the option `-n`.

If a line contains `BEGIN` and then `PRIVATE`, append the next line.

If the appended line does not contain `ENCRYPTED`, output the file name.

---

To use with find:

```
find . -exec sed -n '/BEGIN.*PRIVATE/{N;/\n.*ENCRYPTED/!F;D}' '{}' \;
```

Comment: TIL about sed's F command; thanks. However, your suggestion also fails on file and directory names containing spaces.

$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5

Comment: Perhaps the problem you encounter was to do with find? See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces)